# Existence of a finitely presented simple group satisfying certain properties

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a finitely presented simple group with exactly 8 conjugacy classes of finite subgroups, which have the following respective isomorphism types?

- $C_1$
- $C_2$
- $C_3$
- $C_2^2$
- $C_6$
- $S_3$
- $A_4$
- $D_6$

Comment: @Satan'sMinion: While I agree that the question would benefit from some motivation, your comment is way out of line.

Comment: Do you have any theoretical reason to believe there might? Or do you have a reason why you would like to see such  a group to highlight some particular property?

Comment: @Andy Putman: Ok, I deleted my comment.

Comment: The only f.p. simple groups I know about are either torsion-free (Burger-Mozes, Hyde-Lodha), contain unbounded torsion (Higman-Thompson, Roever-Nekrashevych, Brin-Thompson, etc etc), or have infinitely many torsion conjugacy classes (Caprace-Remy following Kac-Moody). So we don't even have an example with exactly $n$ conjugacy classes of finite subgroups for any $1<n<\infty$, much less with any prescribed isomorphism types.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question? I would have understood if you asked in general about torsion in fp simple groups...

Comment: $D_6$ and $A_4$ are the smallest pair of nonisomorphic non-Abelian groups with isomorphic Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Are you aware of Osin's construction of groups with prescribed conjugacy classes? It is on the arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411039). This can be applied to give finitely *generated* simple groups which contain each of the subgroups you wish, and such that all elements of the same order are conjugate. (So misses on a few counts, but suggests hope...) I suspect promoting the finite generation to finite presentability in his construction would be extremely difficult though.